# References .NET

Tags: c#, .net, dll, reference

I have one project (A) that will develop a logger system. This project will be use for others projects. In project A, there are two references which aren't used in compile time.

When I add a reference in any project to project A, the references aren't imported, but I need them in runtime.

I had seen two solutions:

a) Use dummy code to force the copy in the compile time. This solution seems inelegant.

b) Add the references in others projects. This solution forces to reference always the DLLs

Is there any solution to force the references to be copied?

Thank you so much

Comment: Copying dll's to a runtime or dll directory using the visual studio compiler after build action is another solution. This is for instance common practice when working with prism. It shows low coupling

Comment: You only need to get the file(s) copied.  You can simply add them to your project with Project + Add Existing Item and set their Copy to Output Directory property to "Copy if newer".  If you don't like the clutter then using XCOPY /d in a post-build event can do it as well.

Comment: Sorry but what's the issue in adding the dll as reference in other projects?

Comment: The issue is about knowledge. If I refer to assembly A, should I need to know what other assemblies A need in order to function when referring to it from project B? If I have layered my application into data access, business logic, user interface, why do I need to add refereces for my user interface layer to make sure to include all necessary assemblies required by my data access layer? Why would I even want to? I should be required to add only a reference to my business logic layer, and have dependencies brought along automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the Copy Local property of the specified reference in Project A

EDIT as solution to this case :

> If you are not using those references in compile time then you should
>   add the specific dll files ( add existing item ), as content in Build
>   Action, and with Copy Always option ( in project A ). When the project
>   A gets build, those files will be the build output. This way you can
>   access the files form other projects referencing project A

Comment: Copy Local is true, and it's generated in the bin of Project A. But it doesn't appear in project B

Comment: If you are not using those references in compile time then you should add the specific dll files ( add existing item ), as content in Build Action, and with Copy Always option ( in project A ). When the project A gets build, those files will be the build output. This way you can access the files form other projects referencing project A

Comment: Naumand, it's a good solution!! I can add it as existing item. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Consider making a [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/) package for you project. A NuGet package can ship the run time required libraries and add them to the target project (although I think you may need to use the [PowerShell](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console-powershell-reference) scripting to do that).

You can then use "Manage NuGet references" in the target projects to add your "Project A" and have the NuGet install scripts add the "runtime only" library references"

Remember you can host your own NuGet packages internally, they do not need to be published to the online gallery. We use this approach for internal shared projects as it makes the dependency management and versioning very simple and sensible as well as keeping each project tightly scoped as far as source control goes.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the Assemblys on runtime using Reflection:

```
 Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(path);

 Type t = assembly.GetType("YourClassName");

 object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(t);

 int parameter1 = 1;

 object result = t.GetMethod("The MethodName").Invoke(instance, new object[] { parameter1, "Something" });
```

A bit cumbersome though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to solve the root of the problem - why dont you add the references to the projects that are actualy using them?